# How are the 2 triangles used to prove the centripetal acceleration similar?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

I know that when we prove the centripetal acceleration we use similar triangles that are isosceles. How exactly, can we prove that they are similar, after all those 2 similar triangles could have different angles?

Comment: I've never used similar triangles for centripetal acceleration. Can you elaborate? We don't see what you see.

Comment: A diagram would help!

Comment: Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXJKk7bURmE (at 6:15 the instructor says the angles are equivalent but he doesn't explain why or prove it)

Answer (score 1):

If we call the two radius vectors $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$, then $|\vec r_1| = |\vec r_2|=r$ and the angle between $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ is $\theta$. So the triangle formed by $\vec r_1$, $\vec r_2$ and their difference $\Delta \vec r$ is an isosceles triangle with apex angle $\theta$.

Since the velocity vector is always perpendicular to the radius vector, the angle between $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ will also be $\theta$ (this is why the two triangles have the same apex angle). And $|v_1|=|v_2|=v$. So the triangle formed by $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$ and their difference $\Delta \vec v$ is also an an isosceles triangle with apex angle $\theta$, and so it is similar to the radius triangle. So we have

$\displaystyle \frac {|\Delta \vec v|}{|\Delta \vec r|} = \frac {|v_1|}{|r_1|} = \frac v r$

But $|\Delta \vec r| \approx |\vec v |\Delta t = v \Delta t$ so

$\displaystyle \frac {|\Delta \vec v|}{v \Delta t} \approx \frac v r
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {|\Delta \vec v|}{\Delta t} \approx \frac {v^2} r
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow a = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac {|\Delta \vec v|}{\Delta t} = \frac {v^2} r$

Comment: "Since the velocity vector is always perpendicular to the radius vector, the angle between v⃗ 1 and v⃗ 2 will also be θ (this is why the two triangles have the same apex angle)." I am not too familiar with this postulate that confirms the angles to be congruent. May I know what the postulate is called?

Comment: @FaheemAzeemi If the radius vector rotates through an angle $\theta$ then the velocity vector, which is a tangent to the circle, will also rotate through the same angle. If this is still not clear then draw yourself a diagram.